# NGRX set focus on Input via @Effect

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I've got a Login component.

When it loads, it grabs Username from local storage.

If exists, I would then like to have the focus be set on the Password field.

Currently, I'm doing it in the store subscription.

```
@ViewChild('passfield', { static: false }) passfield: ElementRef;

// ...

this.store.select('login')
  .subscribe(state => {
    this.model.user = state.username;
    if (this.model.user) {
      // focus on pass field if user is not empty
      setTimeout(() => this.passfield.nativeElement.focus(), 0); // <---
    }
  });
```

I want to move that focus to an effect and clear logic from my component.

- Can it be done?
- Can we use view child in effect?
- Do we want to do it ? is there a better approach?

Comment: this may not be relevant to your case, but a big part of the reasoning for removing logic from components is to make your application more portable between platforms.  However, in this case, since the logic is directly DOM related, you may end up making your application LESS portable unless you also provide some kind of service to do this where the implementation can be swapped in and out. But generally, the only logic you WANT in components, is DOM related logic. It's isolation of responsibilities principle, and the isolated responsibility of components is DOM interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite things slightly, but definitely keep the logic in the component:

```js
private destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

this.store.select('login').pipe(
  takeUntil(this.destroy$),
  filter(user => user.username),
  tap(() => this.passfield.nativeElement.focus())
).subscribe();

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next(true);
}
```

I don't think using a side effect to check something in the store from a component to then play with the DOM of the same component is wise. Possible, but unnecessarily complicated.

EDIT: NGRX for state management, components as pure reflections of state. The component should be the one choosing how it interprets a given state.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Can it be done? Can we use view child in effect?

Yes it can be done by create `Component`, then `ViewChild` your `passfield` selector and store it into a `Service` for future usage.

#### 2. Do we want to do it ? is there a better approach?

- `Effects` in `NGRX` implements `Functional Programing` which should not be having side impacts like performing an external actions, change DOM states,... It's designed to allow filtering or changing state of `Store` when dispatch an `Action`. Adding external actions into `NGRX Effects` may lower performance as well since reducer has to check `Effects` every time perform a `Dispatch`
- I normally create a `Factory Module` then pipe to `Observable` to perform similar actions.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'dump-component',
   template: `<input type="password" #pw / >`
})
export class DumpComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild("pw", { static: false }) passfield: ElementRef;

   constructor (public effectStore: DomEffectFactoryService ) {}

   ngAfterViewInit() { 
     this.effectStore.addEffect('focus', this.passfield.nativeElement.focus);
   }
}


class DomEffectFactoryService {
   public dataStore = {};

   addEffect(name, effect) {
     this.dataStore[name] = effect;
   }   

   getEffect(name) {
     return this.dataStore[name];
   }

   trigger(name) {
     return this.dataStore[name]();
   }
}
```

Then in `Subscription`:

```
constructor(public effectStore: DomEffectFactoryService) {}

this.store.select('login')
  .pipe(
   filter(state => state.user),
   tap(state => { this.effectStore.trigger('focus') })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: ngrx effects exist for side effects and reducers should be pure functions. That being said I wouldn't mess with dom in an effect.

Also IMO this is the responsibility of the component not responsibility of the state management.